# Invalid configuration ao salvar Sinônimos no CloudSearch via PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-aws

Estou tentando adicionar sinônimos no CloudSearch via PHP SDK, mas está sempre retornando "Invalid configuration". Estou usando a mesma configuração para Stopwords e funciona normalmente.

Meu PHP:

```
use Aws\CloudSearch\CloudSearchClient;

$this->client = CloudSearchClient::factory(array(
    'key' => MY_KEY,
    'secret' => MY_SECRET,
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
));

$result = $this->client->defineAnalysisScheme(array(
    'DomainName' => MY_DOMAIN,
    'AnalysisScheme' => array(
        'AnalysisSchemeName' => MY_AnalysisSchemeName,
        'AnalysisSchemeLanguage' => 'pt',
        'AnalysisOptions' => array(
            'Synonyms' => $words
        ),
    ),
));
```

Meu JSON ($words):

```
{
  "batman": [
    "coringa",
    "gordon",
    "joker",
    "robin"
  ],
  "raul": [
    "mango",
    "mangolin"
  ]
}
```

Se eu insiro este JSON diretamente no AWS Console ele funciona corretamente.

Está faltando algum parâmetro? Estou fazendo algo errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que seja pela falta do `aliases` (ou alternativamente de um `groups`).

Descrição na [documentação](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-analysis-schemes.html):

```
{
    "groups": [["tool box", "toolbox"], ["band saw", "bandsaw"]],
    "aliases": { "workbench": ["work bench"]}
}

{
    "AnalysisSchemeName": "myscheme",
    "AnalysisSchemeLanguage": "en",
    "AnalysisOptions": {
        Synonyms": "{\"aliases\": {\"youth\": [\"child\",\"kid\"]}}"
    }
}
```

Aplicando ao código

```
$result = $this->client->defineAnalysisScheme(array(
    'DomainName' => MY_DOMAIN,
    'AnalysisScheme' => array(
        'AnalysisSchemeName' => MY_AnalysisSchemeName,
        'AnalysisSchemeLanguage' => 'pt',
        'AnalysisOptions' => array(
            'Synonyms' => array(
                'aliases' => $words
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Eu até tinha tentado assim passando aliases, mas como mexi tanto devo ter trocado mais algo. Agora funcionou. Obrigado.